# Permission denied when trying to install python 3 module

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to install the selenium webdriver module for python on windows, but it always denies my permission to do that.

- I have the selenium folder in my downloads folder
- I have administrator privileges
- I have looked in the internet, but everyone just says "Run it as an administrator."

I am pretty desperate now.
Please help.

Note: PIP does not work for me, for some reason. after trying it with pi, it just say, "module not found". If this is fixed, it is also fine

````
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-28048.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.


D:\Downloads\selenium-3.141.0>```
````

Comment: Please include the exact commands you used , error messages, and code.

Comment: It's not clear how you actually trying to install it

Comment: Done. Now it should be clear

Comment: @Ninto1 Did you got any error message with pip? If no include the code, I want to see how are you importing it. Also use `@` to tag users for them to receive notifications.(like I tagged you in this comment)